# AWS S3 node sdk copyObject NoSuchKey error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

**Update**
I think this may be because of not waiting for `Elastic Trnscoder` to finish the job.

I have an Amazon Elastic Transcoder job initiated by a lambda. I can see the transcoded file in the "out" bucket. I am trying to copy this transcoded file to another bucket, like so:

```
let copyParams = {
 Bucket: "hurontg.video.out.1", 
 CopySource: "hurontg.x3482.video.out/58759ab51e57_transcoded‌​.mp4", // bucket/file exists 
 Key: "58759ab51e57.mp4"
};

 s3.copyObject(copyParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {

  }
)};
```

This results in:

```
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```

As mentioned earlier, I can verify that the source bucket and file exist. Not sure what this error means as the `Key` should be created in the destination bucket?

Comment: If `CopySource: "the_source_bucket/the_transcoded_file",` is your actual code then obviously, this line is wrong, since variables aren't interpolated into quotes like this.  If this isn't your actual code, do you really have a literal string here? If not, what is here?  The error message means there is no such object matching this value.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, `CopySource` is a string literal with value, `'hurontg.x3482.video.out/58759ab51e57_transcoded.mp4'`

Comment: This value should be `/` + `source-bucket-name` + `/` + `object-key`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I think I was not waiting for the transcoding job completion.

Comment: How did you figure it out?

Comment: @KhaledRamadan what issue are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the CopySource is url encoded e.g. `CopySource: encodeURIComponent("hurontg.x3482.video.out/58759ab51e57_transcoded‌​.mp4"),`.

More detail here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property