# NoSuchBucket when calling the CopyObject operation

Tags: python

I try to restore file from old file in s3, only if this file not exist.
My current code is this :

```
import botocore
import os

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def checkFile(filename, buckett="selfmarkett"):
    try:
        s3.Object(buckett, filename).load()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            try:
                _filename, _extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
                oldFilename = _filename + ".p_up" + _extension
                s3.Object(buckett, filename).copy_from(CopySource=oldFilename)
            except Exception as error:
                print("Error2:", error)
```

My problem is, when script try to use funnction copy_from, return this error :

```
NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

the bucket is already specifid in object, how i can fix this error ?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding the bucket name inside the path of the CopySource, like this:

```
s3.Object(bucket, "new_folder/new_file").copy_from(CopySource="<bucket>/old_folder/old_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the language you are coding in but is it possible to provide a second parameter to copy_from?  I suspect you need to specify the bucket and the filename/key in your call to copy_from

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue with the nodeJS api and it's probably the same thing as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492490/2083748 (you need to URL encode the copy source)